# how to enable multiple monitors function of vmware workstation for mac os 10.8.3

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, windows-7-x64, multiple-monitors, vmware-workstation

I have installed Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3 in Windows 7 x64 by VMWare Workstation 9.

And I also have installed vmware tools sucessfully.

I tried to use Cycle Multiple Monitors's function, but vmware says like this. "Can not use Multiple Monitors - ... VMWare workstation does not support the multiple monitors feature in Mac OS X 10.8 64-bit guests. ... "

Can't I use multiple monitors in vmware with Mac OS X ?

Regards.

Comment: Are there any methods to do it?

Answer (score 0):

OSX Virtualization is only supported on Apple hardware platforms. As such, unless your running Windows on your Mac hardware, with Workstation installed inside of that, OSX virtualization isn't officially supported by VMware so there are no guarantees that all features of OSX will function properly.